# cannot run sudo apt --fix-broken install

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.
I cannot use sudo apt install *anything*
The error I get is:

```
[sudo] password for username: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpython3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.15-1+bionic1) but 3.9.5-1+bionic1 is to be installed
 libpython3.9-dev : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.15-1+bionic1) but 3.9.5-1+bionic1 is to be installed
 python3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.15-1+bionic1) but 3.9.5-1+bionic1 is to be installed
 python3.9-minimal : Depends: libpython3.9-minimal (= 3.9.15-1+bionic1) but 3.9.5-1+bionic1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try:
apt --fix-broken install

```
and I get this error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 libllvm9 linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-73 linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-73-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-73-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib
2 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 152 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,486 kB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 214069 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.9-stdlib_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.9-stdlib:amd64 (3.9.16-1+bionic1) over (3.9.5-1+bionic1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.9-stdlib_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.9/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpython3.9-minimal:amd64 3.9.5-1+bionic1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.9-minimal:amd64 (3.9.16-1+bionic1) over (3.9.5-1+bionic1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.9/typing.py', which is also in package libpython3.9-stdlib:amd64 3.9.5-1+bionic1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.9-stdlib_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.16-1+bionic1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried the "Software Updater" and it also reports an error suggesting I try:
sudo apt-get install -f

This also fails with the same (Broken pipe) error as above.

I seem to be going around in circles.
Does anyone have any suggestion as to what I can do next?

Comment: Please add some formatting to make that readable.

Comment: Try to remove the package `libpython3.9-minimal` first.

Comment: @Jos,
  Thanks for your suggestion,
I am new to installing and uninstalling things in Linux,
so please can you give me a command to use to:
"remove package libpython3.9-minimal first" ?

Comment: That would be `sudo apt remove libpython3.9-minimal`. However, if that command replies with a suggestion to remove much else besides this one package, then don't press "y", or you might make things worse.

Comment: @Jos - I did that and got:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpython3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.16-1+bionic1) but 3.9.5-1+bionic1 is     to be installed ... too much to include here, plus another suggestion to:
Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).